# It telling me that I have make a mistake when I am using <td style="color:...;"> on php

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I am trying to make a chart on php which when the number is `2/4/6/8/10 ...` etc. The number will be on white color and it's box on green color, and when the number is `1/3/5/7/9 ...` etc, the number will be on black color and it's box on red color.

Everything is ok but when I am adding `style="color:white(/black);"` and `style="background-color:red(/green);"` on the `<td>` and I am saving it, my window is telling me there is a mistake `background-color/color ...` etc. on this line. Can somebody help me?

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
    echo '<table>'
    for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>  </tr>";
        for ($j=1; $j<=10; $j++) {
            $t= $i * $j;
            if ($j%2==1) {
                echo "<td style="background-color:red;color:black"> $t </td>";
                } else  {
                echo "<td background-color:green;color:white>  $t </td>";
                }
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

I have included the html/head/body etc.

Comment: Welcome! You might want to post the actual error rather than trying to summarise it in your post... that might give more clues to people trying to answer your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1º - You're putting double quotes inside another double quotes!

2º - You've forgotted to put style attribute in the second td!

Change the code below:

```
echo "<td style="background-color:red;color:black"> $t </td>";
} else  {
echo "<td background-color:green;color:white>  $t </td>";
}
```

To:

```
echo "<td style='background-color:red;color:black'> $t </td>";
} else  {
echo "<td style='background-color:green;color:white'>  $t </td>";
}
```

PS.: it's not a good idea to put variables inside double quotes "$var". It should be better if you try like above:

```
echo "<td style='background-color:red;color:black'>". $t ."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change one of the sets of quotes to single quotes in the echo statement
 You are exiting the statement otherwise which will give you an error.

```
echo "<td style='background-color:red;color:black'> $t </td>";
```

And second echo doesn't contain style attribute at all. This also needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using double qoute for entire. Echo statement that's fine but also using double qoute inside the same statement which is wrong.  Change that to single quotes.